# Rspec: Using Let with context correctly?

Tags: ruby, rspec

So im constructing a automation framework (Currently using RSpec with Capybara) using a page object model setup. Im somewhat used to RSpec but unsure if what im doing is correct:

```
RSpec.describe 'Login', type: :feature do

  after(:all) do
    Capybara.current_session.quit
  end
  context "valid login" do
    let(:login_page) {LoginPage.new(Capybara.current_session)}
    it 'should login successfully and show dashboard' do
      expect(login_page.log_in.session).to have_content('Dashboard')
    end

    it 'should logout successfully after login' do
      dashboard = login_page.log_in
      expect(dashboard.log_out.session).to have_content('Log In')
    end
  end

  context "invalid login" do
    let(:login_page) {LoginPage.new(Capybara.current_session)}
    it 'should fail to log in successfully and display alert' do
      expect(login_page.log_in('bademail@email.com', 'badpassword').session).to have_content('bad login info')
    end

    it 'should give an error when not entering an email' do
      expect(login_page.log_in('', 'badpassword').session).to have_content('Please enter email')
    end
  end

end
```

Specifically since im handling sessions manually, im wanting it to quit after each `context` but it's quitting the session after the describe block.

Also im not sure if I am using `let` correctly. As im trying to capture the current session before each `it` block and create a new page object.

(Maybe a secondary ruby question, but are variables created with `let` destroyed after the `it` block or?)

Thanks

Comment: If you put a breakpoint or `puts` call in your `after(:all)` block, you will see that it's only called once. As for your second question, _yes_, variables with `let` are destroyed after the `it` block, and it looks like you're using `let` fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` by itself doesn't get called unless you use it with `!` as `let!`. Without `!` let behaves as method definition so it won't get used before you call it in `it` block. `let!` will get called before each `it` example similar to `before` block.

This means that if you want to clear your code a bit, you can use `let` only once in `describe` block outside of `context` blocks and then just call it in `it` blocks as you do now.

As for `after(:all)` it will be called only once after all tests are done. If you would like to use it after each suit `after(:each)` is the way to go. You can read more about this here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

Looking at your example I am not sure if using this `after` block is necessary - Capybara should reset session after each `it` example unless there is any other setup. (I might be wrong here - haven't worked much with Capybara).